# Number made of 4 chars with hex

Tags: c++, char, int, hex

Iam programming in C++ and Iam comming with another "stupid" problem. If I have 4 chars like these:

```
char a = 0x90
char b = 0x01
char c = 0x00
char d = 0x00
```

when that all means hexadecimal number 0x00000190 which is 400 decimal number.
How do I convert these chars to one int? I know i can do

```
int number = a;
```

but this will convert only one char to int. Could anybody help please?

Comment: unsigned Number = unsigned(a) | (unsigned(b) << 8) |  (unsigned(c) << 16) |  (unsigned(d) << 24)

Comment: @DieterLücking still no good; if `char` is signed then `unsigned(a)` is `0xFFFFFF90`  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
int number = (a & 0xFF)
           | ((b & 0xFF) << 8) 
           | ((c & 0xFF) << 16)
           | ((d & 0xFF) << 24);
```

It would be simpler with unsigned values.

Comment: why the masking? it's completely unnecessary and makes the whole expression hard to read

Comment: Thank you so much and the others too :) It works now, but sadly i dont have idea how it works. The shifting thing :/

Comment: Could you please tell me, what exactly the "masking" with 0xFF00 etc. does?

Comment: Look at bitwise operator [AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Comment: Nice, besides left shift of negative numbers is undefined (5.8 Shift operators)

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
int number = ((d & 0xff) << 24) | ((c &0xff) << 16) | ((b & 0xff) << 8) | (a & 0xff);
```

the `<<` is the bit shift operator and the `& 0xff` is necessary to avoid negative values when promoting `char` to `int` in the expression (totally right by Jarod42)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
unsigned char ua = a;
unsigned char ub = b;
unsigned char uc = c;
unsigned char ud = d;

unsigned long x = ua + ub * 0x100ul + uc * 0x10000ul + ud * 0x1000000ul
```

It is like place-value arithmetic in decimal but you are using base 0x100 instead of base 10.

If you are doing this a lot you could wrap it up in an inline function or a macro.

---

Note - the other answers posted so far using bitwise operations on `(char)0x90` are all wrong for systems where plain `char` is signed, as they are forgetting that `(char)0x90` is a negative value there, so after the integral promotions are applied, there are a whole lot of `1` bits on the left.

Comment: That's why I used masking also.