# Hex *char from int number

Tags: c++, hex, bit-shift

I asked here how to convert 4 chars to int number here: [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224041/number-made-of-4-chars-with-hex)

It is working but now I need to do the same but in reverse. I want to make 4 chars from one int. Because I dont understand completly bit shifting and using OR and AND operators in practise so I tried to solve my problem with stupid solutions like converting first the int to Hex String then to char, etc. Could anybody help me here with good solve please? Sorry for my english.

Comment: If your system is little-endian, you could probably get away with memcpy'ing one into the other. Don't quote me on that!

Comment: Would a `union` fit your bill?

Comment: Post your code or at least what you are trying to do with pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to do the same but in reverse. I want to make 4 chars from one int.

Just do the operations in reverse. Shift to right instead of left and mask after shift instead of before:

```
char bytes[4];
long number = 0x00000190L; // int may be only 2 bytes on some implementations
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (number >> (8 * i)) & 0xFFL;
}
```

If your intention is to get a hex string instead (like the title suggests, but which is not the reverse of the linked question), then the simplest thing to do is to use `std::hex` and a stream.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what i need :) Working!

Answer (score 2):

Here could be an acceptable solution, manipulating pointers. An excellent tutorial about pointers can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

```
int main()
    {
      int test32 = 0 ;
      int* ptest32 = &test32;

      char* p1st8bits = (char*) ptest32;
      char* p2nd8bits = p1st8bits + 8;
      char* p3nd8bits = p1st8bits + 16;
      char* p4nd8bits = p1st8bits + 24;

      std::cout  <<"first 8 bits: " << *p1st8bits << "\n" ;
      std::cout  <<"second 8 bits: " << *p2nd8bits << "\n" ; 
      std::cout  <<"third 8 bits: " << *p3nd8bits << "\n" ;
      std::cout  <<"fourth 8 bits: " << *p4nd8bits << "\n" ;
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty clever, thanks for it. But for me wasnt working really well. But i was only my bad.

Comment: this is a good solution, but be careful though because you could get an access violation if you don't offset the pointer correctly. bit shifting is safer in that perspective

Comment: Well, it depends. The chances you have an access violation when using pointers and making an error (like accessing the 33rd bit) can be quickly reduced to zero by testing the code and making sure correct characters are obtained. If it works once, it will always work. Bitshifting can be misleading with signs and different compiler behaviors. I'd say both solutions are great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const unsigned int value = 0x12345678;
std::ostringstream hex_stream;
hex_stream << hex << value;
```

The above fragment will convert the value to a hex string.  The following snippet will print the characters one per line.

```
std::string chars_as_hex = hex_stream.str();
for (i = 0; i < chars_as_hex.length(); ++i)
{
  std::cout << chars_as_hex[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use bit shifting:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void main(void* args)
{
  // 4 byte integer
  unsigned int charInteger = 0;

  // 4 characters
  unsigned char c1 = 'a';
  unsigned char c2 = 'b';
  unsigned char c3 = 'c';
  unsigned char c4 = 'd';

  // put each character above into each byte of a 4 byte integer
  charInteger = (c1 & 0xFF)
       | ((c2 & 0xFF) << 8) 
       | ((c3 & 0xFF) << 16)
       | ((c4 & 0xFF) << 24);

  std::cout << "charInteger = " << charInteger << "\n";

  // get each byte of the integer
  unsigned int i1 = charInteger & 0xff; // first byte
  unsigned int i2 = (charInteger >> 8) & 0xff; // second byte
  unsigned int i3 = (charInteger >> 16) & 0xff; // third byte
  unsigned int i4 = (charInteger >> 24) & 0xff; // fourth byte

  // display each byte of charInteger as characters
  std::cout << char(i1) << "\n";
  std::cout << char(i2) << "\n";
  std::cout << char(i3) << "\n";
  std::cout << char(i4) << "\n";

  std::string h;
  std::cin >> h;
}
```

Comment: i should have just converted each byte back to chars, instead of ints then casting them to chars when displaying them, but i thought this was easier to see that you are getting the value of each byte of the integer

Comment: Thanks for answer with the explanation. I got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
const char* chars = (const char*)&number;
```

And now you can access the chars as they are in the array:

```
chars[0], chars[1], chars[2], chars[3]
```

Same you can actually do in reverse:

```
char chars[4];
// write each char in to array
int *pnumber = (int*)chars;
// now you can read the number: 
int number = (*pnumber);
```

Order here is important and it depends on endiannes of your system.